# Get data from bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm trying to get the date values to query my database. I keep getting `undefined`. I have checked all the documentation and I cannot find a way to get data. [I'm using this bootstrap datetime](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker) picker

**HTML file:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="to" class="col-md-2 control-label">Start Date</label>
    <div class="input-group date to col-md-5" data-date="2017-01-01T05:25:07Z"  data-link-field="dtp_input1">
        <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" readonly>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="from" value="" /><br/>
</div>
```

**JavaScript file:**

```
$(".to").datetimepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-ddThh:ii:ssZ",
    onSelect: function() {
        endValue = $(this).datetimepicker('getDate');
    }
});

//console.log(endValue);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".to").datetimepicker()
        .on('change', function( evt ) {
        startValue = $('#to').val();

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an `onSelect` event in the docs at all so I'm not sure where you're getting that from. Nor a `getDate`. You can get the value from the same input the datepicker is assigned to. Once you get to the last screen of the datepicker widget, it 'changes' the value of the associated input. Listen for `change` events on that box to know when it's happened.

```
$(".to > .form-control").on('change', function( evt ) {
    var date = $(this).val();
    console.log( date ); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This didn't work for me. Still not getting any data.

Comment: @Ekom just realizing that the class `.to` was on the wrapper `div`, not the `input` itself. See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance I found the solution.

Comment: @Ekom what was the solution?